# fast and concurrent algorithm of frequency calculation in elixir

Tags: algorithm, erlang, elixir, word-count

I have two big lists that their item's lengths isn't constant. Each list include millions items.
And I want to count frequency of items of `first list` in `second list`!

For example:

```
a = [[c, d], [a, b, e]]
b = [[a, d, c], [e, a, b], [a, d], [c, d, a]]

# expected result of calculate_frequency(a, b) is %{[c, d] => 2, [a, b, e] => 1} Or [{[c, d], 2}, {[a, b, e], 1}]
```

Due to the large size of the lists, I would like this process to be done concurrently.
So I wrote this function:

```
  def calculate_frequency(items, data_list) do
    items
    |> Task.async_stream(
      fn item ->
        frequency =
          data_list
          |> Enum.reduce(0, fn data_row, acc ->
            if item -- data_row == [] do
              acc + 1
            else
              acc
            end
          end)

        {item, frequency}
      end,
      ordered: false
    )
    |> Enum.reduce([], fn {:ok, merged}, merged_list -> [merged | merged_list] end)
  end
```

But this algorithm is slow. What should I do to make it fast?

**PS**: Please do not consider the type of inputs and outputs, the speed of execution is important.

Comment: [`Flow`](https://hexdocs.pm/flow/Flow.html) is your friend here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this fast enough and certainly it's not concurrent. It's `O(m + n)` where `m` is the size of `items` and `n` is the size of `data_list`. I can't find a faster concurrent way because combining the result of all the sub-processes also takes time.

```
data_list
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn(item, counts)-> 
  Map.update(counts, item, 1, &(&1 + 1)) 
end)
|> Map.take(items)
```

FYI, doing things concurrently does not necessarily mean doing things in parallel. If you have only one CPU core, concurrency actually slows things down because one CPU core can only do one thing at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Put one list into a `MapSet`.

Go through the second list and see whether or not each element is in the `MapSet`.

This is linear in the lengths of the lists, and both operations should be able to be parallelized.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by normalizing the data you want to compare so a simple equality check can tell if two items are "equal" as you would define it. Based on your code, I would guess `Enum.sort/1` would do the trick, though `MapSet.new/1` or a function returning a map may compare faster if it matches your use case.

```rb
defp normalize(item) do
  Enum.sort(item)
end

def calculate_frequency(items, data_list) do
  data_list = Enum.map(data_list, &normalize/1)
  items = Enum.map(items, &normalize/1)
end
```

If you're going to get most frequencies from data list, I would then calculate all frequencies for data list. Elixir 1.10 introduced `Enum.frequencies/1` and `Enum.frequencies_by/2`, but you could do this with a reduce if desired.

```rb
def calculate_frequency(items, data_list) do
  data_frequencies = Enum.frequencies_by(data_list, &normalize/1) # does map for you

  Map.new(items, &Map.get(data_frequencies, normalize(&1), 0)) # if you want result as map
end
```

I haven't done any benchmarks on my code or yours. If you were looking to do more asynchronous stuff, you could replace your mapping with `Task.async_stream/3`, and you could replace your frequencies call with a combination of `Stream.chunk_every/2`, `Task.async_stream/3` (with `Enum.frequencies/1` being the function), and `Map.merge/3`.